# I have javascript code that splits the screen, however, how do I run it from a flex application?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, browser

So, this code splits the screen into two frames:

```
Javascript:A14nH=location.href;L3f7="http://www.google.com";R1Gh7="http://www.google.com";if(L3f7&&R1Gh7){Fr4Q='<frameset%20cols=\'*,*\'>\n<frame%20src=\''+L3f7+'\'/>';Fr4Q+='<frame%20src=\''+R1Gh7+'\'/>\n';Fr4Q+='</frameset>';with(document){write(Fr4Q);void(close())}}else{void(null)}
```

I need to run this code from a flex application and what I am doing is:

```
   var jsFunc:String = "function () { location.href=\"javascript:A14nH=location.href; L3f7=\"http://www.google.com\";R1Gh7=\"http://www.google.com\";if(L3f7&&R1Gh7){Fr4Q=\"<frameset%20cols=\"*,*\">\n<frame%20src=\"\"+L3f7+\"\"/>\";Fr4Q+=\"<frame%20src=\"\"+R1Gh7+\"\"/>\n\";Fr4Q+=\"</frameset>\";with(document){write(Fr4Q);void(close())}}else{void(null)}\"}";
   var divExists:Boolean = ExternalInterface.call(jsFunc);
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

(Btw, if you change `var jsFunc:String = "function () { location.href='http://www.google.com' }";` the page does take you to Google)

Comment: And why is that :)? ohh, and maybe since I am a l33t, you can help :)

Comment: m28, I don't understand your suggestion, where? could you provide the example :)

Comment: Putting "()" at the end of a function calls the function immediately after it is declared with the arguments inside the parenthesis.  I believe that is what he's telling you, just in a more condescending way.

Comment: So do I just add "()" after the last } I have in the var jsFunc:String ? Because that did not change anything. I really appreciate your help Ryan

Comment: Try replacing the '%20's in the string with spaces.

Comment: Your quotes were not escaped properly; see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your "allowNetworking" parameter of the object and embed tags of Flash is set to true. With that parameter, the whole ExternalInterface package becomes severely limited.

Also, it may be a better idea to store the javascript along with the HTML. Then, from AS3, you can call the js function using `ExternalInterface`.

IN ActionScript: `ExternalInterface.call(myJavascriptFunc)` will call `myJavascriptFunc` if it is loaded in the same page as the Flash application.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am not embedding flash in HTML, I am building a flex application (flash application using the flex framework).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can call the eval function and pass it the JavaScript you want it to execute:

```
var jsFunc:String = "location.href=\"javascript:A14nH=location.href; L3f7=\"http://www.google.com\";R1Gh7=\"http://www.google.com\";if(L3f7&&R1Gh7){Fr4Q=\"<frameset%20cols=\"*,*\">\n<frame%20src=\"\"+L3f7+\"\"/>\";Fr4Q+=\"<frame%20src=\"\"+R1Gh7+\"\"/>\n\";Fr4Q+=\"</frameset>\";with(document){write(Fr4Q);void(close())}}else{void(null)}\"";
var divExists:Boolean = ExternalInterface.call("eval", jsFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the first location.href assignment and leave the code you want executed:

```
var jsFunc:String = "function () {
    lA14nH = location.href;
    L3f7 = \"http://www.google.com\";
    R1Gh7 = \"http://www.google.com\";

    if (L3f7 && R1Gh7) {
        Fr4Q = '<frameset%20cols=\'*,*\'>\n<frame%20src=\''+L3f7+'\'/>';
        Fr4Q += '<frame%20src=\''+R1Gh7+'\'/>\n';
        Fr4Q += '</frameset>';

        with (document) {
            write(Fr4Q);
            void(close())
        }
    }
    else {
        void(null)
}";
var divExists:Boolean = ExternalInterface.call(jsFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not escaping quotes propertly.
2. `ExternalInterface.call()` expects a javascript statement to execute - you're passing the definition of a function, but not calling it. As already suggested, append a `()` to the end to call the passed function.

I believe I've escaped the quotes properly. Try this and let me know what happens.

```
var js:String = "function () { ";
js += "location.href=\"";
js += "javascript:A14nH=location.href;";
js += "L3f7 = \"http://www.google.com\";";
js += "R1Gh7 = \"http://www.google.com\";";
js += "if(L3f7&&R1Gh7){ ";
js += "Fr4Q= \\\"";
js += "<frameset cols='*,*'><frame src='\\\" + L3f7 + \\\"'/>\\\"; ";
js += "Fr4Q+=\\\"<frame src='\\\" + R1Gh7 + \\\"'/>\\\"; ";
js += "Fr4Q+=\\\"</frameset>\\\"; ";
js += "with(document){write(Fr4Q);void(close())} ";
js += "}else{void(null);} "
js += "\"} ()";
var divExists:Boolean = ExternalInterface.call(js);
```

If you pass

```
"alert('something');"
```

to `ExternalInterface.call`, it will execute it and you'll get an alert. But if you pass

```
"function(){alert('something');}"
```

it just creates an anonymous function. To call the function, you have to add `()` to it as in

```
"function(){alert('something');}()"
```

This is same as creating a named function and calling it like:

```
function test(){alert('something');}
test();
```

you can even pass parameters this way:

```
"function(text){alert('Got ' + text);('taDaa!!')}"
```